# How to change the original button text after button loader using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have using bootstap button loader
I need to change the button text when clicking of Save button and during the process it is showing loader icon without any issue. But after that i have to change button text Save to  Save & continue.
I have tried a lot but value button text is reseting to original staate

Below is the code i have used.

Js:

```
$('#addtchSave').on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.button('loading');

            var touchpointNmae = $("#tname").val();
            var touchpointDesc = $("#tdesc").val();
            $.ajax({
             url: '/Home/addpoint?tchname=' + tNmae + '&tchdesc=' tDesc,
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    myObject = result;
                    $this.button('reset');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $this.button('reset');
                    }, 2000);
                },
                error: function () {
                }

            });
            $("#addtchSave").val("Save and Continue");
       });
```

Cshtml:

```
   <button type="button" id="addtchSave" data-loading-text="Saving <i    
   class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i>" class="btn btn-
   primary">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$("#addtchSave").val("Save and Continue");
```

with

```
 $("#addtchSave").text("Save and Continue");
```

Comment: when do you want the button text to change "Save and Continue". As soon as you click the button or when the ajax completes ?

Comment: When Ajax completes I need